# Build two jar files from same ANT build file

Tags: java, build, ant

I am trying to build two jar files - one only with the classes related to the application and the other including the test cases. However the two jars generated are having both the classes and test cases.

PFB the snippet of the build XML.

```
<target name="compile" description="generate the distribution" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" debug="${debug}" destdir="${basedir}/dist/classes">
            <classpath refid="class.path" />
        </javac>
        <jar jarfile="${dist}/${jarname}.jar" basedir="${basedir}/dist/classes">
            <metainf  dir="${src}/META-INF"  includes="beans.xml" />
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="compilewithtest" description="generate the distribution with test" depends="init,compile">
        <javac srcdir="${test}" debug="${debug}" destdir="${basedir}/dist/classes">
            <classpath refid="class.path" />
        </javac>
        <jar jarfile="${dist}/${jarnamewithtest}.jar" basedir="${basedir}/dist/classes">
            <metainf  dir="${src}/META-INF"  includes="beans.xml" />
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy">
        <antcall target="clean" />
        <antcall target="compile" />
        <antcall target="compilewithtest" />
        <antcall target="junitreport" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/dist" />
        <delete dir="${basedir}/report" />
    </target>
```

Is it not possible to generate two jars from the same classes directory? How do  I resolve this issue?

EDIT -

It is working if the class directories are different. Is it not possible to use the same directory. The below highlighted section is redundant.

```
<target name="compile" description="generate the distribution" depends="init">
        **<javac srcdir="${src}" debug="${debug}" destdir="${basedir}/dist/classes">**
            <classpath refid="class.path" />
        </javac>
        <jar jarfile="${dist}/${jarname}.jar" basedir="${basedir}/dist/classes">
            <metainf  dir="${src}/META-INF"  includes="beans.xml" />
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="compilewithtest" description="generate the distribution with test" depends="init,compile">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" debug="${debug}" destdir="${basedir}/dist/class">
            <classpath refid="class.path" />
        </javac>
        **<javac srcdir="${test}" debug="${debug}" destdir="${basedir}/dist/class">**
            <classpath refid="class.path" />
        </javac>
        <jar jarfile="${dist}/${jarnamewithtest}.jar" basedir="${basedir}/dist/class">
            <metainf  dir="${src}/META-INF"  includes="beans.xml" />
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy">
        <antcall target="clean" />
        <antcall target="compile" />
        <antcall target="compilewithtest" />
        <antcall target="junitreport" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/dist" />
        <delete dir="${basedir}/report" />
    </target>
```

Comment: Can you do this :
Compile/Create jar without test,Clean the directories,Compile/Create jar with test

This should work

Comment: No this is not working. I am receiving the below error.

..\dist\classes" does not exist or is not a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below template should work :

```
<target name="compile">
    <antcall target="clean" />
    <!-- javac and jar without test-->
</target>
<target name="compilewithtest">
    <antcall target="clean" />
    <!-- javac and jar with test-->
</target>
<target name="deploy">
    <antcall target="compile" />
    <antcall target="compilewithtest" />
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <!-- Delete and create required directories -->
</target>
```

So that for every compilation/building of jar, "clean" is executed. Further I will suggest to use same target for compilation/jar creation for multiple jars by parameterizing the target for source/destination folders.

Answer (score 0):

Below changes based on the above inputs have resolved the issue.

```
<target name="compile" description="generate the distribution" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" debug="${debug}" destdir="${basedir}/dist/classes">
            <classpath refid="class.path" />
        </javac>
        <jar jarfile="${dist}/${jarname}.jar" basedir="${basedir}/dist/classes">
            <metainf  dir="${src}/META-INF"  includes="beans.xml" />
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="compilewithtest" description="generate the distribution with test">
        <antcall target="clean" />
        <antcall target="init" />
        <javac srcdir="${src}" debug="${debug}" destdir="${basedir}/dist/classes">
            <classpath refid="class.path" />
        </javac>
        <javac srcdir="${test}" debug="${debug}" destdir="${basedir}/dist/classes">
            <classpath refid="class.path" />
        </javac>
        <jar jarfile="${dist}/${jarnamewithtest}.jar" basedir="${basedir}/dist/classes">
            <metainf  dir="${src}/META-INF"  includes="beans.xml" />
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy">
        <antcall target="clean" />
        <antcall target="compile" />
        <antcall target="compilewithtest" />
        <antcall target="junitreport" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/dist/classes" />
        <delete dir="${basedir}/report" />
    </target>
```